# How to convert a complex string into Hash in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is a `complex_string` which we would like to convert into Hash {:stats => str1, :search => str2}:

```
:stats =>  {<%=t('Payment Total($)') %>:&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= number_with_precision(number_with_delimiter(@s_s_results_details.models.joins(:contract => :payments).sum(:paid_amount)), :precision => 2) %>
<%=t('Contract Total($)') %>:&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= number_with_precision(number_with_delimiter(@s_s_results_details.models.joins(:contract).sum(:contract_amount)), :precision => 2) %>},
:search =>  {}
```

In the end, we would like to assign str1 and str2 to 2 variables. We tried to use `eval(complex_string)` and there is error:

```
"(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting end-of-input :stats => {<%=t('Payment Tota...          ^"
```

It seems that the `=>` in the string causes error. Is there a way we can convert `complex_string` into hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code that works for that particular case:

```
complex_string = ":stats =>  {<%=t('Payment Total($)') %>:&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= number_with_precision(number_with_delimiter(@s_s_results_details.models.joins(:contract => :payments).sum(:paid_amount)), :precision => 2) %>
<%=t('Contract Total($)') %>:&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= number_with_precision(number_with_delimiter(@s_s_results_details.models.joins(:contract).sum(:contract_amount)), :precision => 2) %>},
:search =>  {}"

hash = {}
complex_string.scan(/^:(\S+) =>  ({.*?}),?$/m).each do |m|
  hash[m[0].to_sym] = m[1]
end

hash # => {:stats=>"{<%=t('Payment Total($)') %>:&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= number_with_precision(number_with_delimiter(@s_s_results_details.models.joins(:contract => :payments).sum(:paid_amount)), :precision => 2) %>\n<%=t('Contract Total($)') %>:&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= number_with_precision(number_with_delimiter(@s_s_results_details.models.joins(:contract).sum(:contract_amount)), :precision => 2) %>}", :search=>"{}"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you build it in your controller and respond with json?